# DirectX (probably after update) makes my system freeze

Tags: windows-7, freeze, directx

Lately I bought Counter Strike: Global Offensive and Installed it on my Windows 7 SP1 64-bit system.
The game came with DirectX 11 patch that was installed (I would say successfully).

The problem is that after the game was installed the computer froze completely.

I'm not sure if the directx is the one to blame, And I'm not really sure if this game patch caused that (might be earlier windows update).

I do know that DirectX causes my computer to freeze and not only with this game. For example, When I'm trying to log-in to Skype my computer freezes as well. Debugging the process with OllyDbg, show that it get's access denied (and there were some references to d3d10.dll on the stack, so i assume it must be related).

I'm facing a problem, I don't really know what to do. Is there a way to remove the directx completely and reinstall it from scratch?

**EDIT:** I've tried upgrading my Geforce GT 220 to the latest driver, didn't help. I've even tried installing th directx again (before upgrading the driver) didn't help as well.